# Can't implement Google login with Next-auth.js

Tags: authentication, next.js, next-auth, react-google-login

I'm having trouble getting google login works on my project with Next.js and Next-auth.
Next.js: 13.2.4
Next-auth: 4.22.1
Here is my code so far:
https://github.com/Suprefuner/airbnb-clone
I keep getting 'PKCE code_verifier cookie was missing.' error or 'State cookie was missing.' error.
Stuck for days, anyone knows how I can fix it? Thanks!!